# Dynamic forms in Slickedit

Tags: slickedit

I want to know if we can create dynamic dialog boxes in slickedit by reading the the value of form elements from an external file (.txt file) . If yes , how ??

Answer (score 0):

Please give an example of what your .txt file could have

but the short answer would be - did you look yet at the macros dir?
There are plenty of dialog examples there.  For example I used the `project_load()` as a template for a dialog that used an external file list.

Please look at that function and respond